# SELECT TOP 1 MAX(DATETIME)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Suppose I have a table called `'@DeviceSample'` and another table called `'@DevicesActivityDataSample'.`

I want To SELECT top 1 `'MAX(DATETIME)'` FROM `'@DevicesActivityDataSample'` for each Device BUT when I had Duplicated rows In 'DevicesActivityDataSample' In My result I get all Duplicated rows but I looking for top one. 
and another problem is when I want select from 100000 rows it take long long time to get my result because of calculating MAX this is my sample code

```
DECLARE @DeviceSample TABLE
(
RowID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
ADeviceID INT ,
DeviceName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
) 
INSERT @DeviceSample
SELECT 1,'DEVICE 1' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'DEVICE 2' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'DEVICE 3'



DECLARE @DevicesActivityDataSample TABLE
(
RowID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
BDeviceID INT,
DeviceDateTime DATETIME,
CMD NVARCHAR(50)
) 

INSERT @DevicesActivityDataSample
SELECT 1, '2013-02-14 19:08:46.000','HHJJ' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2013-02-15 03:30:24.000','HHJJ' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2013-02-15 03:30:24.000','HHJJ' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2013-02-15 03:30:24.000','HHJJ' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '2013-02-16 03:30:24.000','HHJJ' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '2013-02-11 03:30:24.000','HHJJ' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2013-02-10 03:30:24.000','HHJJ' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '2013-02-07 04:25:24.000','HHJJ' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '2013-02-12 23:02:02.000','HHJJ' 



    SELECT  *
    FROM        @DeviceSample
    INNER JOIN  
    @DevicesActivityDataSample 
            ON  ADeviceID = BDeviceID
    WHERE       DeviceDateTime IN (
                    SELECT    MAX(DeviceDateTime) AS MaxDate
                    FROM      @DevicesActivityDataSample                                
                    GROUP BY  BDeviceID
                ) 

GO
```

and How can I get fast fast fast  result for 1000000 rows or more rows

Comment: Why are you putting 1000000 rows into a table variable? And is fast fast fast a lot faster than fast? What is your definition of fast (and fast fast fast)?

Comment: I  try to visualizer My database  for that question

Comment: Well it will probably be faster if you *don't* shove a million rows into a temporary object.

Comment: How many different `DeviceID` are there in the million row table?

Comment: @Martin   15000 Device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a greatest n per group query. Changing the definition of your table variable to

```
DECLARE @DevicesActivityDataSample TABLE (
  RowID          INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  BDeviceID      INT,
  DeviceDateTime DATETIME,
  CMD            NVARCHAR(50),
  UNIQUE (BDeviceID, DeviceDateTime DESC, RowID, CMD) )
```

to add a useful index.

#### Method 1

```
SELECT DADS.*
FROM   @DeviceSample DS
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   @DevicesActivityDataSample DADS
                    WHERE  DADS.BDeviceID = DS.ADeviceID
                    ORDER  BY DADS.DeviceDateTime DESC) DADS;
```

#### Method 2

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BDeviceID 
                                       ORDER BY DeviceDateTime DESC) AS RN
         FROM   @DevicesActivityDataSample)
SELECT *
FROM   T
WHERE  RN = 1
```

[image: Plans]

You might also consider using a `#temp` table as @Aaron suggests perhaps with the following definition.

```
CREATE TABLE #DevicesActivityDataSample (
  RowID          INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
  BDeviceID      INT,
  DeviceDateTime DATETIME,
  CMD            NVARCHAR(50)) 

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX ON #DevicesActivityDataSample(BDeviceID, DeviceDateTime DESC)
```

Do you actually need `RowID` at all?

Comment: Not actually But Justin case

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT DeviceID, MAX(DeviceDateTime)
FROM @DeviceSample
GROUP BY DeviceID;
```

If this is slow then consider using a #temp table instead of a @table variable ([see the major differences here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server)), and add an index like:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX LatestDeviceTime
  ON #DeviceSample (DeviceID, DeviceDateTime DESC);
```

Or not using a table variable or temp table in the first place, and adding a useful index to the base table where the data comes from.

Comment: But In your select we get deviceID and DeviceDateTime  but I need all column of @DevicesActivityDataSample